# Skip where clause based on condition from collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to write a collection in which i put multiple where clause. But depending on some conditions i want to execute some where clause and skip some of them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the when() method.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses
For example:

```
DB::table('products')
->when($request->active, function($query) {
    $query->where('active','=',true);
})
->when(isset($request->category), function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('category','=', $request->category);
})
->get();
```